# Why using AngularJS directive in comments

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, use-case

As you know (probably), AngularJS provides ability to create directives based on comments (M).

But why ?

What is the use case ? Any idea ?

One of my students asked me and I was not able to provide any examples... Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Use-Case, from the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> **Best practice:** Comment directives were commonly used in places where the DOM API
>   limits the ability to create directives that spanned multiple elements
>   (e.g. inside `<table>` elements). AngularJS 1.2 introduces
>   [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) as a better solution to this
>   problem. Developers are encouraged to use this over custom comment
>   directives when possible.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Types](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#directive-types)

The "M" restriction is used the least often, usually only for backwards compatibility and for passing markup validations.

Answer (score 1):

i am thinking of something like `ng-if` it put a commented html that indicate the place that an element can be inserted if matching criteria, may be it has it's own cases people will use it.